# YOLO model: passing m exemples to the model?Tensorflow issue with placeholders

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, yolo

I am trying to do transfer learning in order to use the pretrained YOLO model of the coursera deep learning specialization. 
The YOLO model does image detection and recognition: so I wanted to add to this model same additional layers in order to identify the gender of the detected object.

So, I have m images and I try to pass them through the existing YOLO model in order to get the output and use these outputs as a training set for the new added layers.
Here is where my issue occurs: when I try to pass the m examples in one line code: i got an error...

I will specify all the steps done and the obtained output:

**Importing the libraries**

```python
import argparse
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import scipy.io
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Conv2D
from keras.models import load_model, Model
from yolo_utils import read_classes, read_anchors, generate_colors, preprocess_image, draw_boxes, scale_boxes
from yad2k.models.keras_yolo import yolo_head, yolo_boxes_to_corners, preprocess_true_boxes, yolo_loss, yolo_body
from keras.models import Sequential
from scipy.misc import imread
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline
```

**Importing the dataset:

2155 images of shape (608,608,3)**

```python
train=pd.read_csv("datset.csv",sep=';')
train_img=[]  
for i in range(len(train)):
    (img, train_img_data)=preprocess_image('path_dataset'+train['ImageURL'][i],model_image_size = (608, 608))
    train_img.append(train_img_data)
train_img= np.array(train_img)
train_img=train_img.reshape(2155,608,608,3)
```

**Verifying the dataset dimensions**

```python
print('shape of train_img: ',train_img.shape)
print("shape of first element in train_img: ",train_img[0].shape)
print("reshaping first element in tran_img: ",train_img[0].reshape(1,608,608,3).shape)
```

**Output of dataset dimensions**

```python
shape of train_img: (2155, 608, 608, 3)
shape of first element in train_img:  (608, 608, 3)
reshaping first element in tran_img:  (1, 608, 608, 3)
```

**Importing the Yolo model**

```python
yolo_model = load_model("model_data/yolo.h5")
```

**feeding the YOLO model with the train_img in order to get the output which will be used as a training set for the added layers.**

```python
sess = K.get_session()
output=sess.run([yolo_model.output], feed_dict={yolo_model.input: train_img , K.learning_phase(): 0})
```

**The error that i get:**

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1360     try:
-> 1361       return fn(*args)
   1362     except errors.OpError as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1339           return tf_session.TF_Run(session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1340                                    target_list, status, run_metadata)
   1341 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    515             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 516             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    517     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2155,608,608,32] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
     [[Node: conv2d_1/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_1_0_1, conv2d_1/kernel/read)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-067537a70066> in <module>()
      1 sess = K.get_session()
----> 2 output=sess.run([yolo_model.output], feed_dict={yolo_model.input: train_img , K.learning_phase(): 0})

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    903     try:
    904       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 905                          run_metadata_ptr)
    906       if run_metadata:
    907         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1135     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1136       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1137                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1138     else:
   1139       results = []

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1353     if handle is None:
   1354       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1355                            options, run_metadata)
   1356     else:
   1357       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1372         except KeyError:
   1373           pass
-> 1374       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1375 
   1376   def _extend_graph(self):

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2155,608,608,32] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
     [[Node: conv2d_1/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_1_0_1, conv2d_1/kernel/read)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.


Caused by op 'conv2d_1/convolution', defined at:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 478, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-11-c868ea7b7486>", line 7, in <module>
    yolo_model = load_model("model_data/yolo.h5")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 243, in load_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 317, in model_from_config
    return layer_module.deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 144, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2524, in from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2481, in process_node
    layer(input_tensors[0], **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 619, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 168, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 3335, in conv2d
    data_format=tf_data_format)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 781, in convolution
    return op(input, filter)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 869, in __call__
    return self.conv_op(inp, filter)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 521, in __call__
    return self.call(inp, filter)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 205, in __call__
    name=self.name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 717, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2155,608,608,32] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
     [[Node: conv2d_1/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_1_0_1, conv2d_1/kernel/read)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

**please note**
the placeholders for the input are of size **(None,608,608,3)** so if I send a dataset of size **(2155,608,608,3)** there should be no problem(that's what I couldn't understand). Adding to this, if I feed the network with an example of size **(1,608,608,3)**, i got no error!  I could iterate over all elements in my data_set and feed the network 2155 times ( each time I feed it with (1,608,608,3) ), but this is time consuming and not the best way to do.
By the way, I thought that the None in the placeholder is used so I could send m training examples at the same time.

I really couldn't understand what the error is according to the output. I am waiting for your help to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error tells you it's Resource Exhaustion error. So your ram is most likely the problem, since you don't seem to train on CPU.
And a tensor with 1*608*608*3 entries is much smaller then one with 2155*608*608*3, so there is your explanation. Solution is simply: Just train with a smaller batch_size.

Comment: I am also working on yolo transfer learning. how you are passing label information